# Generalize guesstimate for number of people doing activity at this instant

Tags: estimation, fermi-problems

From [Guesstimation 2.0](https://www.amazon.in/Guesstimation-2-0-Solving-Today%60s-Problems/dp/069115080X) question $2.8$:

> Q: How many people are talking or texting on their cell phones at this
> instant?
>
> The key insight to solve a problem like this is that the fraction of
> time the average person spends doing some activity is equal to the
> fraction of people doing it right now.
> ...
> $$\frac{t_{talk}}{t_{day}} = \frac{N_{talk}}{N_{day}}$$
> ...

I understand this. But this works only when we are talking about the entire world (and the assumption that people doing this activity are uniformly distributed).

If the question is only for a specific region, how would this insight change? For instance, how many people are sleeping *in your state* at this instant? This fraction of people would be significantly different (more or less) from $\frac{8}{24}$ (assuming an average of $8$ hours/day).

Comment: Well, you'd need a model of some sort.  Something that takes into account the extraneous variable (nighttime).  There isn't a one-size-fits-all approach.

Comment: @lulu could you give an example? Can we extend the stated formula?

Comment: Modeling is complicated!  The percentage of people who will go swimming today differs wildly between Hawaii and Siberia.  And that's an obvious variable...in your example, I'd worry that cell phone technology wasn't uniformly distributed globally and that this might mess up simple assumptions (just for an example of a less obvious external variable).  If you want to analyze external variables, you need pertinent data.

Comment: Hmm. I wasn't as much concerned about the uniformity assumption. I thought there might be some generalization of the 'entire world' thing (probably assuming uniformity still).

Comment: For context, I was asked this in an interview - How many people are present in supermarkets at this instant in your country? (an estimate was expected)

Comment: Well, that seems only vaguely related to what you posted.  For that question, I'd hazard that the average household goes to buy groceries $2$ times a week (a guess, but I doubt I'm far off, at least for the States).  Then I'd declare $30$ minutes per visit. (both numbers could be pretty wrong).  So  then I'd just need to guess how many households there are and then make sensible assumptions concerning the hour of the day.

Comment: With this sort of problem, "getting it right" is usually not the goal.  Make clear, sensible assumptions and indicate how strongly you believe in each of them.  Make a solid argument as to how those assumptions lead to a value and indicate clearly where the weak points in your argument are.